# svn export command line to export files from subversion with wildcard in filenames or extension

Tags: svn, cmd, tortoisesvn

I have a repository in [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) which comprises `.cpp`, `.h`, `.txt` and other files.

I want to export only the `.h` files to specified local directory.

I'm getting an error with this code:

```
svn export --username %SVN_USER% --password %SVN_PASSWORD% --force --non-interactive "http://justatest.com/svn/repos/TrackingProjects/*.h" c:\exported_files
```

Is there a support a wildcard support for this? I have workaround for this but I just want know if this is possible in `svn` command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The export command does not accept wildcards. How about a workaround script? This gets a list of files from the repo directory, filters the desired ones, then exports them individually.

```
@echo off
set "DESTDIR=C:\exported_files"
set "REPODIR=http://justatest.com/svn/repos/TrackingProjects"
set "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\exfiles.tmp"
svn ls "%REPODIR%" | findstr /R "\.h$" >"%TEMPFILE%"
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('type "%TEMPFILE%") do (
    svn export "%REPODIR%/%%~f" "%DESTDIR%"
)
if exist "%TEMPFILE%" (del "%TEMPFILE%")
exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks lit. Yeah I have this kind of workaround where I export the whole project then then loop to each files. Thank you for confirming that wildcard is not supported. Hopefully they will soon. I guess I have to stick to this work-around.

Comment: @lit Thanks for script. How the clause:  in ('type "%TEMPFILE") should looks in this case? how the 'type should be resolved? This syntax is strange.

Comment: @Marek-A-, I have made two (2) small, but significant, corrections in the script. This `type` command is the Windows command.